# Solving $ \sqrt{ \frac{11 \cdot \sin(x)^2 - 2}{\sin(x)^2} + 5 \cdot \cot(x)} = 3 - \cot(x) $

Tags: trigonometry

I can't figure out how to solve these equations:

$$ \sqrt{ \frac{11 \cdot \sin(x)^2 - 2}{\sin(x)^2} + 5 \cdot \cot(x)} = 3 - \cot(x) $$

The answer should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align} \sqrt{ \frac{11 \cdot \sin^2(x )- 2}{\sin^2(x)}+5 \cdot \cot x} = 3 -\cot x  \end{align}
Square both sides,

\begin{align}  {11 \sin^2(x) -2}+2.5 \sin 2x = 8 \sin^2x +1 -3\sin2x \end{align}
\begin{align}  \Rightarrow 3 \sin^2(x) -3 +5.5\sin2x =0 \end{align}
\begin{align}  \Rightarrow 1.5 (1-\cos2(x) )-3 +5.5\sin2x =0 \end{align}
\begin{align}  \Rightarrow    11\sin2x  -3\cos2x -3=0 \end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much, but I didn't understand the first line. Can you describe it in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$\frac{11  \sin(x)^2 - 2}{\sin(x)^2} =\frac{11  \sin(x)^2 - 2\sin(x)^2-2\cos(x)^2}{\sin(x)^2} =9-2\cot(x)^2$$

Make $t=\cot(x)$, square, solve for $t$ and check if squaring did or not introduce extra solutions.